# Errors when installing MySQL community server

Tags: mysql, installation

Im trying to install MySQL community server... Though i get the same error everytime I try to install it. Anyone?

Screenshot:
http://gyazo.com/91ad5b84fbf3427663aa38b57e4d48fb

The error log:

```
1: 
1: Action 19:51:53: INSTALL. 
1: 1: MySQL Server 5.6 2: {319E6998-5D33-44F0-926F-671C8773B0BE} 
1: Action 19:51:53: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
1: Action 19:51:53: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
1: Action 19:51:53: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
1: Action 19:51:53: ValidateProductID. 
1: Action 19:51:53: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 19:51:53: FileCost. Computing space requirements
1: Action 19:51:53: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
1: Could not access network location \Hewlett-Packard\\.
1: Could not access network location \Hewlett-Packard\\.
1: 1: MySQL Server 5.6 2: {319E6998-5D33-44F0-926F-671C8773B0BE} 3: 3 
1: 
1: Final actions.
1: Install error
```

In advance,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go into regedit and look in the registry under these two keys:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninsta‌​ll\ HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

If you see an "InstallLocation" value containing \Hewlett-Packard\

just delete it

hers is the link

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/aedd0f90-5779-45e1-85fb-f71cb12166fc/mysql-install-error-on-new-computer-windows-7-professional?forum=w7itproappcompat